# Ant installation cannot find maven-artifact-ant-2.0.4-dep.jar

Tags: maven, ant

I'm trying to install Ant on Windows 7 using [these](http://ant.apache.org/manual/index.html) instructions, but at stage 5, when I run the command `ant -f fetch.xml -Ddest=system`, I get the following error:

> `Buildfile: C:\Program Files\WinAnt\fetch.xml
>
>   pick-dest:
>
>        [echo] Downloading to C:\Program Files\WinAnt\lib
>
>   probe-m2:
>
>   download-m2:
>
>        [echo] Downloading to C:\Program Files\WinAnt\lib
>
>         [get] Getting: http://ibiblio.org/maven2//org/apache/maven/maven-artifact-ant/2.0. /maven-artifact-ant-2.0.4-dep.jar
>
>         [get] To: C:\Program Files\WinAnt\lib\maven-artifact-ant-2.0.4-dep.jar
>
>         [get] Error opening connection java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://ibiblio.org/maven2//org/apache/maven/maven-artifact-ant/2.0.4/maven-artifact-ant-2.0.4-dep.jar
>
>         [get] Error opening connection java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://ibiblio.org/maven2//org/apache/maven/maven-artifact-ant/2.0.4/maven-artifact-ant-2.0.4-dep.jar
>
>         [get] Error opening connection java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://ibiblio.org/maven2//org/apache/maven/maven-artifact-ant/2.0.4/maven-artifact-ant-2.0.4-dep.jar
>
>         [get] Can't get http://ibiblio.org/maven2//org/apache/maven/maven-artifact-ant/2.0.4/maven-artifact-ant-2.0.4-dep.jar to C:\Program Files\WinAnt\lib\maven-artifact-ant-2.0.4-dep.jar
>
>   BUILD FAILED
>
>   C:\Program Files\WinAnt\get-m2.xml:85: Can't get http://ibiblio.org/maven2//org/apach/maven/maven-artifact-ant/2.0.4/maven-artifact-ant-2.0.4-dep.jar to C:\Program Files\WinAnt\lib\maven-artifact-ant-2.0.4-dep.jar
>
>   Total time: 1 second`

I understand that the URL is not reachable, so I tried to enter this URL into my browser, and indeed it does not exist. I found the file `maven-artifact-ant-2.0.4-dep.jar` at:

`http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-artifact-ant/2.0.4/maven-artifact-ant-2.0.4-dep.jar`

instead. So how can I fix this problem?

Comment: I've installed ANT so many times, I haven't read the install doco in quite a while. Didn't know this "fetch.xml" file existed. +1 for something I learnt today

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just need to update the m2.url property in the lib/library.properties file to http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2.

Comment: It runs but during the installation there are more errors... More unknown URLs. The whole thing is broken. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: Override the "m2.url" property as in the answer below and it will work. If you're located behind a corporate firewall, then you'll need to set additional **http.proxyHost** and **http.proxyPort** properties.

Answer (score 8):

Run ANT as follows

```
$ ant -f $ANT_HOME/fetch.xml -Ddest=user -Dm2.url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2
```

The m2.url property needs to be overloaded. The following property file in ANT needs to be updated:

```
$ANT_HOME/lib/libraries.properties
```

Using a now deprecated Maven Central URL

Answer (score 2):

The URL is correct, but you're trying to download the files into a subfolder of `Program Files` (C:\Program Files\WinAnt\lib). To do so you need to be running your commands with Administrator rights.

So right click on your Command Prompt shortcut and select "`run as administrator`" or enter "`cmd`" into the search field of the start menu and press CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER.

Then try to run the ant command again:

```
ant -f fetch.xml -Ddest=system
```

And if you have trouble downloading any other files using the script, it seems to work well to just download them using your browser, put them in the right place, and then edit `fetch.xml` to **not** download the file.